# Q about Vuetify checkbox align

Tags: checkbox, alignment, vuetify.js

How can I align Vuetify checkbox to the right?

```
<div style="height:20px; *alignment: right*">
    <v-checkbox label="checkbox"></v-checkbox>
</div>
```

I think the above settings are invalid, then How can I?
Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With flexbox, you can do something like this:

```html
<div style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid black; display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
  <div style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red;"></div>
</div>
```

So your code would look something like this:

```
<div style="height:20px; display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
    <v-checkbox label="checkbox"></v-checkbox>
</div>
```